# push notification ios

Tags: ios, firebase, push-уведомления

Есть ios приложение, с бэкендом в firebase(авторизация, бд, пуш).
Проблема в том, что в стандартной его конфигурации пуши можно отправлять только из консоли. А нужно сделать так, чтоб можно было отправлять пуши прямо из приложения.
Как я понял, надо писать свой сервер. Есть ли тогда толк от их сервисов? Или может есть способ без написания сервера?
В общем, вопрос - как проще всего из текущей ситуации сделать нормальную отправку уведомлений?

Comment: firebase за вас пуши не отправляет, потому что они не знают вашу бизнес логику - в какой ситуации и какой пуш надо отправить. Возможно у них есть какие то стандартные темплейты, но писать все равно вам.

Comment: По всей видимости Вам необходимо сначала понять как работают Push  нотификации, чтобы не возникало вопросов. Хороший материал для старта тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/156811/. А так вероятнее всего писать свой сервер. Ну или второй вариант, если они продвинутые, то может у них есть свой API для отправки кастомных нотификаций из приложения. Скажем передаете push id и playload через некий запрос и нотификация отправиться. Изучайте их документацию.

Comment: "Написание сервера" как такового не обязательно. Лично я создал ветку в базе, в которую устройства записывают пуш, который нужно отправить. У меня есть скрипт на питоне и программа на go (~100 строк) которые с помощью двух библиотек с джитхаба следят за этой веткой через REST API и отправляют их. Сервер не нужен, можно хоть на домашнем ПК запускать бинарник/скрипт, но лично у меня он на виртуальном хостинге. Могу поделиться, если интересно

Comment: Хотя это в принципе годный материал для статьи на хабре, только вот руки никак не доходят написать

Comment: Был бы очень рад такой статье, вряд ли без неё я разберусь в питоне и го) Вообще я сделал напрямую чтоб всё отправлялось, прямо с устройства (правда гугл крайне не рекомендует так делать, но я по-другому пока не разобрался)